# where can I find a good wordlist

Tags: dictionary, words, thesaurus

I'm looking for a file that is a wordlist and also is set up by type of word. For example something in this format

```
Nouns: {
    bus
    car
    deck
    elephant
    ...
}
Adjectives {
    awful
    bashful
    ...
}
Advervb {
    ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See also: [stackoverflow.com/questions/2288953/Separate word lists for nouns, verbs, adjectives, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288953/separate-word-lists-for-nouns-verbs-adjectives-etc). Could your question be a duplicate of the one I linked?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is a good list of nouns / verbs ...

Nouns

http://www.momswhothink.com/reading/list-of-nouns.html

Verbs

http://www.momswhothink.com/reading/list-of-verbs.html

Adverbs

http://www.momswhothink.com/reading/list-of-adverbs.html

Answer (score 7):

The [MOBY](http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/) word list is almost exactly what you're looking for: http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mpos.html

This list also builds on the MOBY list: http://www.ashley-bovan.co.uk/words/partsofspeech.html

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that the word type depends on usage and context.  For example, 'root' can be a noun or verb.

On a Unix/Linux system with `aspell` installed, this will give you all the words in the dictionary:

```
aspell dump master
```

Finally, see the related question:  [Need free English dictionary or Corpus, ultimately for a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892802/need-free-english-dictionary-or-corpus-ultimately-for-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1):

Most flavors of linux ship with a file called dictionary. It's got all English words you might want, but they are not categorized.

Comment: Where is this `dictionary` file located? I'm aware of `words`. The words file is usually stored at `/usr/share/dict/words` or `/usr/dict/words`.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain human readable output, you need to use ASPELL twice:

aspell -d en dump master | aspell -l en expand > words

at least according to: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10619/dump-an-aspell-dictionary-as-a-word-list

Here is an example:

```
aspell -d en dump master | aspell -l en expand
...
abases
abbesses
abscess
abscess's
abscissa
abuser's
abusers
abuse's
abuses
abysses
...
```